# QML Display multi text in one ROW

Tags: qt, qml, qtquick2

I have problem in displaying the text inside a listview in aligned manner.

MyCodes are

```
                delegate: Rectangle{

                    width : parent.width
                    height: textId.implicitHeight+20
                    color: "white"
                    border.color: "#e4e4e4"
                    radius: 0
                    RowLayout{
                        anchors.fill: parent
                        anchors.margins: 20
                        Text{
                            id:textId
                            text : names
                        //    wrapMode: Text.Wrap
                          //  Layout.fillWidth: true
                           // width:300
                        }
                        Text{
                            id:textId2
                            text :favoriteColor
                          //  wrapMode: Text.Wrap
                            //Layout.fillWidth: true
                            //width: parent.width
                           // width:300
                        }

                        Text{
                            id:textId1
                            text :age
                           // wrapMode: Text.Wrap
                          //  width: parent.width
                        }
                    }
```

Output is
[image: Output]

I am expecting the textfields i.e. names, favoriteColor and age to come in more aligned manner. In Simple words showing in simple table form. 
i.e. All Favoritecolors and age to start from same point throughout the list.

Thank You

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should fix width of `textId2` and `textId1` using [Layout.preferredWidth](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-layouts-layout.html#preferredWidth-attached-prop) and  [Layout.maximumWidth](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-layouts-layout.html#maximumWidth-attached-prop), and assign `true` to [Layout.fillWidth](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-layouts-layout.html#fillWidth-attached-prop) for `textId`.

Answer (score 0):

```
        RowLayout{
            anchors.fill: parent
            anchors.left: parent.left
            anchors.leftMargin: 10
            anchors.verticalCenter: parent.verticalCenter
            layoutDirection: Qt.LeftToRight
            spacing: 10

            Text {
                id:textId
                text :favoriteColor
                Layout.maximumWidth: advance.width
                Layout.preferredWidth: advance.width
            }

            Text {
                id:textId1
                text :age
                Layout.fillWidth: true
            }
        }
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value. A good answer will always have an explanation of what was done and why it was done in such a manner, not only for the OP but for future visitors to SO.